# Woodrugh's way of holding a gun is taken from where?

Tags: true-detective

Woodrugh from the 2nd season of *True Detective* is a soldier, that is clear. The authors of the series love details and we can see a different way of charging, holding the gun and walking in a zone where hostility is expected. Every one of the three cops do it in their own way.

What was the inspiration for Woodrugh's style? He's on the right here:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called the Centre Axis Relock, or CAR system.

[image]

Woodrugh still shoots from a conventional firing position, but his holstered/resting position is with his gun pulled close to his chest, barrel pointed out at the expected direction of fire. Whilst holding a weapon at arm's range can increase aim and stability if using a high calibre weapon (especially absorbing recoil), this grip is considered better in small spaces with low calibre weapons.

Not only does it create a stance from which it is possible to present a smaller target area to any assailants, it also allows the holder to fire from cover whilst still moving without too much adjustment.

It's also an effective way to carry a weapon if wearing full combat gear, which given that Woodrugh was a former soldier would also make sense as to why he is more comfortable with it.

The main advantages of this stance are increased **weapon retention**. It's much more difficult to take someone by surprise and force them to drop their weapon (or even disarm them) if their weapon is held too tightly to their chest. As most people (seasoned vet's included) reflex reaction to a loud noise (such as a gunshot) is to flinch and draw the arms in, in a combat situation that movement can cost valuable seconds: the CAR system eliminates that reaction, as the arms have nowhere to move back to.

Comment: Congrats for wining bounty for [3rd best answer of this quarter](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/1981/1190)

Answer (score 0):

No native speaker, so finding google terms is hard:

http://gearpatrol.com/2014/02/11/guide-to-life-how-to-hold-and-fire-a-handgun-properly/

> Point 6: Keep it in what’s called the ready position (Fig 6), holding the gun close to your body in front of your abdomen and pointed toward your target.
>
> Point 8: Now, from the ready position, extend your arms out in front of you and prepare to aim in on your target with your dominant eye.

So the front guy is using this technique. The one behind him is maybe trying to avoid pointing his gun at the front guy? And since he can't shoot throuh him anyay, maybe he is pointing at the middle of the open area he sees? All guesses just, interested in the real reason am I.